# Broke old cable bottom bracket cable router and can't find like for like, can I buy another?

Tags: vintage, transmission

Unfortunately broke a Shimano sm-sp25 cable router for 90s Marin. It seems the spacing between the two cable is 25mm.

Online I only find sm-sp17 and sm-sp18.

Can I buy one of those? or any other?

Thanks!

Comment: I bought some new plastic ones on aliexpress for cheap - they were perfectly serviceable.

Answer (score 3):

Any will do, it doesn't have to be made by shimano. I suggest you liberate one from a scrap bike rather than buy new.

Answer (score 2):

A search on eBay yielded a few SM-SP25 cable guides for sale. Typically found at vintage bike parts stores on eBay.  They are a bit pricey it seems, perhaps owing to it's all-metal construction. The SM-SP18 has the same spacing and accommodates two cables.

Interestingly, you could just use a couple short lengths of derailleur housing under the BB shell. The tension of the inner cable keeps them in place.

Comment: I thought that sm25 meant 25mm between the two cable and 18 would have a different spacing. If they are the same then yes I would get a sm18. Otherwise I will try and get the original one on ebay. Thanks

Comment: I couldn't locate any measurements, but [here are a couple versions of the SP18](https://www.universalcycles.com/shopping/product_details.php?id=6695). The two holes in the M5 bolt on version allow you to have some lateral adjustment.  I've used it differently on different bikes. In one case I chose to use the hole that made the guide sit farther to the right allowing more rear der cable clearance at the rear tire. Another time I recall setting the guide left so that the guide's lead up the seat tube lined up to where the inner cable contacted the front der.